# Javascript request to Python Django not found

Tags: javascript, python, json, django, request

I am new to Django and Javascript. Now totally stuck with this error, probably a really small thing, but I can not figure out what can be the problem.

I would like to delete a document through my form using Javascript and send it to my Django backend through a request. At the terminal I get this error message:

```
"Not Found: /delete_document/7/
[23/Feb/2024 13:26:53] "DELETE /delete_document/7/ HTTP/1.1" 404 2371"
```

The request color is yellow and it happens as I see, it just can not find my view function.

**views.py**

```
@require_http_methods(['DELETE'])
def delete_document(request, document_id):
    document = get_object_or_404(Document, pk=document_id)
    document.delete()
    return JsonResponse({'message': 'Document deleted successfully'}, status=204)
```

**urls.py**

```
from django.urls import path

from . import views

# Define namespace
app_name = 'advice'

urlpatterns = [
    ...
    path('delete_document/<int:document_id>/', views.delete_document, name='delete_document'),
]
```

**index.html relevant parts**

```
    <form id="documentForm" action="" method="post" data-base-action="{% url 'advice:gpt_base' %}">
        {% csrf_token %}
        <input type="hidden" name="firstQuestion" value="True">
        <select id="documentSelect" class="form-select" aria-label="Select form">
            <option selected>Select a file</option>
            {% for document in documents %}
                <option value="{{ document.id }}">{{ document.title }}: {{ document.uploaded_file.url }}</option>
            {% endfor %}
        </select>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" id="deleteButton">Delete</button>
        <br>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
    </form>
    <script>
        document.getElementById('deleteButton').addEventListener('click', function() {
            var selectedDocumentId = document.getElementById('documentSelect').value;
            if (selectedDocumentId === 'Select a file') {
                alert('Please select a document to delete.');
            } else {
                if (confirm('Are you sure you want to delete this document?')) {
                    fetch(`/delete_document/${selectedDocumentId}/`, {
                    method: 'DELETE',
                    headers: {
                        'X-CSRFToken': document.querySelector('input[name="csrfmiddlewaretoken"]').value
                    }
                })
                    .then(response => {
                        if (response.ok) {
                            // Reload the page to reflect changes
                            window.location.reload();
                        } else {
                            console.error('Failed to delete document');
                        }
                    })
                    .catch(error => console.error('Error:', error));
                }
            }                
        });
    </script>
    <script>
        document.getElementById('documentSelect').addEventListener('change', function() {
            var selectedDocumentId = this.value;
            var form = document.getElementById('documentForm');
            var baseAction = form.getAttribute('data-base-action');
            form.action = baseAction + selectedDocumentId + '/';
        });
    </script>
```

Everything working okay, except the Delete button because of that error.
Please help me solve it. Thanks in advance!

I tried to delete a document in a form sending a request with Javascript, it resulted an error in the terminal with the error message above. Tried to solve this in every possible way, ChatGPT did not find any error in the code and seemed like a good implementation for it.

Comment: Have you included the `advice.urls` in the project's `urls.py` file?

Comment: Yes, everything was included perfectly. Except one tiny mistake, which I found now. At the fetch part, I had to replace this 'fetch(`/delete_document/${selectedDocumentId}/' with 'fetch(`delete_document/${selectedDocumentId}/' and removed the "\" in the beginning of the url. Sorry for the long post... :)

Answer (score 0):

I just found this tiny mistake. At the fetch part, I had to replace: `fetch(/delete_document/${selectedDocumentId}/` with `fetch(delete_document/${selectedDocumentId}/`
and remove the "" from the beginning of the url.

Sorry for the long post.. :)

Ps: I hope this will help others to spare 2 hours who has similar problem